# How to change the height on SVG so that the user won't have to scroll down?

Tags: html, css, svg

This is [the page](https://seefar.org/locations/) I'm working on, please take a look at it. I have to resize the height of it so that the user won't have to scroll down.

This is the SVG code is [here](https://codepen.io/elieobeid7/pen/zbWMMQ), too long to fit in a SO question the page is

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Locations
*/
get_header(); 
$regions = get_field('regions');
$testimonials = get_field('locations_testimonials');
$time_of_each_slide = get_field('time_of_each_slide');
?>

<section id="locations" class="clearfix wrapper">
<div class="row"  style="background-color:white;">
<div class="col-xs-11 col-xs-push-1">
<h2>Places where we work</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 padding-0" id="location-map-wrap">
    <span id="tooltip"></span>
    <?php echo get_field('region_map_svg'); ?>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" id="location-side-bar">
    <div id="location-detail" data-timer="<?php echo $time_of_each_slide; ?>">
    <h3>What our beneficiaries say about us...</h3>
    <div class="inner clearfix">

    <?php foreach($testimonials as $testimonial): ?>
        <div class="testimonial">
            <div class="text"><?php echo $testimonial['testimonial']; ?></div>
            <div class="author"><?php echo $testimonial['author']; ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <a href="/projects" class="cta-btn">Learn more about our projects</a>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I don't know where the rest of the code is, it's a WordPress site, so getting the full code is tricky and I'm not the one who created the site, but again, all I want is to resize the SVG so that it fits the page above without scrolling, I've included the code to that.

What I've tried:

- Giving width and height to `SVG`, that messed up the site
- Giving width and height to `#map`, that did not do anything
- Change the height of the wrapper div, that crops the SVG
- Changing the viewport of the SVG, that messes it up
- Entering width and height in the SVG, but that would crop the SVG

Comment: I don't know the answer, but this looks like an excellent resource: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Comment: A good place to start investigating would be the fact that a style tag is placed before `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the rendered HTML, that can't be good. I think a lot of weirdness happening all over the place is caused by this. Notice how [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpDKx.png) looks in Chrome DevTools vs [your site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqW3j.png).

Comment: @SeinopSys Your comment was so helpful, I think I just solved the issue using it. Could you please post an answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not part of the question itself, the actual rendered HTML of your site looked like this:

```
<style>…</style> <!DOCTYPE html>  <html lang="en-GB" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <head> …
```

According to the [HTML 5 specification](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#doctype-declaration) the doctype has to be at the start of the document. Otherwise, your page will be interpreted using various legacy rendering methods that might not conform to HTML5 standards. This could very well have been the reason why none of your attempts to position the SVG properly worked as you would've expected.

That being said, for positioning the image itself, I would suggest the use of the `vh` viewport unit. With [relatively good browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) you can combine it with `calc()` to size any element relative to the viewport size. If you know that,  for example, your header is `200px` high then you can use the following to fit the SVG snugly under it:

```
svg {
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```

This doesn't only work with images, but with any element as well, so you could apply this to your columns instead and use `height: 100%` on the content within them for a similar effect.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was so helpful